# Using Django with jQuery in changing the image of the link

Tags: jquery, django

Good day to everyone. I'm newbie in web development and have started learning it with Django framework. Everything was OK, until I have to use the jQuery. This is the problem code...

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE HTML...
...
<head>
<script src="{% static 'jquery-1.10.2.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#downloadswap img').hover(function() {
  $(this).attr('src', "{% static 'fdownloadbook.png' %}");
}, function() {
  $(this).attr('src', "{% static 'downloadbook.png' %}");
});
</script>
...
<a href = "#" id = "downloadswap"><img src="{% static 'downloadbook.png' %}"></a>
```

My aim is to change the image when user mouse over the link with the help of JS. But it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the jquery code in a [DOM ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#downloadswap img').hover(function() {
      $(this).attr('src', "{% static 'fdownloadbook.png' %}");
    }, function() {
      $(this).attr('src', "{% static 'downloadbook.png' %}");
    });
});
```